# insert data into mysql database - java eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

i have this code to insert data into mysql db, when i run on eclipse the following code it doesn't show any errors but no data are inserted into the db.
this is my code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) { 

    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_spie"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","lecci"); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database_spie.notifiche(titolo, destinatario, testo) \r\n" + 
                "VALUES ('inizio', 'tutti', 'spie per una notte inizia tra 30 minuti');");
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("closed");
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: you don't actually execute the statement.

Comment: exactly, you need to use st.executeUpdate();

Comment: ok, i added st.executeUpdate() but it shows that i have to add url in execute.Update(). like st.executeUpdate(url). But then when I run the project thi error is shown "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_spie' at line 1"

Comment: You need to use PreparedStatement not Statement,if using statement pass query string to execute update.check my answer

Comment: thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point is you need to use PreparedStatement  not Statement.

You have only created connection, created query and then closed connection

```
PreparedStatement    st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO database_spie.notifiche(titolo, destinatario, testo) \r\n" + 
                "VALUES ('inizio', 'tutti', 'spie per una notte inizia tra 30 minuti');");
```

//Before closing connection you need to execute it using following line of code

```
 st.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
```

You should follow these steps: source (https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-update-query-example)

- Create a Java Connection to our MySQL database.
- Create a SQL UPDATE statement, using the Java PreparedStatement syntax.
- Set the fields on
  our Java PreparedStatement object
- Execute a Java PreparedStatement
- Close our Java database connection. Catch any exceptions that may
  come up during the process

If you are using Statement then you need to do it like below

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

//pass the query string to it
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO database_spie.notifiche(titolo, destinatario, testo) \r\n" + 
                    "VALUES ('inizio', 'tutti', 'spie per una notte inizia tra 30 minuti');");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not executed the statement, just created it then closed the connection.

there is an execute() method on the PreparedStatement object.